# How create a graph of battery?

Tags: android, graph, battery

I wish create a graph of battery usage in my application..How can i do it? I only want a simple graph not a complicated thing. I've seen about this site http://www.achartengine.org/ but i don't understand how use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last time I needed to draw a graph, I used the GraphView library:

https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView

It's easy to use and you have a demo application here:

https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos

Try it out and report.

Comment: Thank you when i go home try.. One one thing.. But where have i to write the parameter for the battery usage in this graph? Have you ever draw it for the battery usage?

Comment: If you open demo app in src/AdvancedGraph you have somethng like    data[i] = new GraphViewData(i, Math.sin(v));. 

You change your method to something like:
data[i] = new GraphViewData(BatteryTimeInSeconds, BatteryPercent);

Or something alike. BatteryTimeInSeconds = x value and BatteryPercent = y value of graph.

Try other examples as well (CustomLabelFormatterActivity.java is good to use with time, if you would like to measure how the battery percentage was changin by time).

Comment: Thank you..only last one thing, how have i import the library?i tried to put the graphview-3.1.jar in my libs folder of my project but nothing happen. gets me 42 errors because it doesn't find the library.

Comment: Import the demo app and then import the library. Both as different projects. If you use eclipse choose the library project, right click Properties>Android see Library and check "Is Library".

Then check demo app project, click Properties>Android Library - Add.. and then choose the previous library. 

In Eclipse under project you have "Android Dependencies" and in that folder the GraphView jar must be seen after this.

Comment: It works thanks, later i'll try better :) thank you

Comment: @David_D  i m getting issues in GraphViewSeries class i m getting error  Multiple markers at this line
 - GraphViewSeries cannot be resolved to a type
 - The constructor GraphViewXML(GraphViewData[]) is 
  undefined
 - GraphViewSeries cannot be resolved to a type